# How to send push notification from user to user?

Tags: ios, push-notification

Trying to send push notification from user-to-user, UserA is bidding on the value for an item. Scenario, UserA updates a value in the app and clicks send, and at the same time UserB gets a notification of the updated value.

```
       If UserB approves of the message(value) {
           UserA gets gets the notification of approval and proceeds to 
      final step of buying the item. 
 }  else {
sends no and UserA is updated of the denial and he sends a new value for approval
}
```

A guide to accomplish the task would be greatly appreciated.

P.S using firebase as backend

Comment: One option is: https://stackoverflow.com/q/44246237/442121

Answer (score 0):

Since you are already using Firebase, you have it pretty easy.

This tutorial explains everything you need to do this:

https://www.raywenderlich.com/140836/firebase-tutorial-real-time-chat-2

Essentially you need to do two things:

1. Save data to the Firebase database. (User A)
2. Listen for new data being saved to the database. (User B)

Additionally, the firebase docs themselves explain this pretty well: https://firebase.google.com/docs/cloud-messaging/ios/topic-messaging

Comment: That would just observe the changes if the app is opened, I think he wants real system notifications

Comment: @RobertD.Mogos yes thats true !! The end user should be able to receive the notification of the change irrespective of the status of the app.

Answer (score 0):

You can use Firebase with the cloud messaging. So `UserA` creates the item. `UserB` is interested so he would subscribe to a topic about that item.

And every time there is an update, he would get a notification. Check this https://firebase.google.com/docs/cloud-messaging/ios/topic-messaging

Answer (score 0):

Sending Push Notifications is done with Apple Push Notification Service. Apple provides a [documentation](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/NetworkingInternet/Conceptual/RemoteNotificationsPG/APNSOverview.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40008194-CH8-SW1) on how to use APNs.

The basic principal is illustrated in this picture.

[image: Apple's Documentation on APNs]

Sending Messages from one device directly to another is not the way it works. You have to send a notification to the APNs in order to push them to another devices.

Since you are using Firebase I would recommend using [Firebase Cloud Messaging](https://firebase.google.com/docs/cloud-messaging/) to send Push Notifications.

If you just need real time updates in the app [Firebase event listeners](https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/ios/lists-of-data#listen_for_child_events) should work just fine.